# System Program Problem Detected

Tags: system, apport

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, fully up-to-date. I'm new to Ubuntu. Whenever I start my system I face "System Program Problem Detected." Why is this happening? I ran `sudo rm /var/crash/*` but it again appears after some time. What could be at fault?

Comment: By fully-updated, its 12.04.2, right? 'coz there are a lot of bug fixes in 12.04.2.

Comment: stop the still-running apport service:`sudo stop apport` after deleting crash and doing @Ian's answer.

Comment: I read your question and sudo rm /var/crash/* solved my problem. The problem started to happen after I could not wake up my laptop from hibernate and did a cold reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 right now and faced the problem. It helped me.
[System Program Problem Detected](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11218099)

```
sudo sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/g' /etc/default/apport
```

Comment: That's what @Ian posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable `apport`.

To do so, follow these steps:

- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksu gedit /etc/default/apport`.
- Open the file and change the value of `enabled` from `1` to `0`.
- Save and exit. Reboot.

***Source:*** http://www.prescottlinux.com/2012/linux-news/how-to-disable-system-program-problem-detected-errors-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: disabling doesn't solve this.

Comment: Simply disabling apport doesn't solve the problem. It's just a workaround and potentially harmful one.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen: Although about two years and three months later, would you like to say how to actually solve this problem or at least mention the problem's source? Additionally, in Ubuntu 15.04?

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/apport
```

And hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Change the text "enabled=1" to "enabled-0". Then, save and exit.

To solve this problem, you can watch this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFzGxdzFg04).

Comment: You should add the steps required to solve the problem. Then you can mention the source.

Comment: steps are in the video

Comment: Atleast write a summary of steps.

Comment: ok, wrote a summary