# what is "System program problem detected" notification about and how to fix it?

Tags: system, notification, system-settings, apport

I will start by saying this is not a duplicate of [System Program Problem Detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163025/system-program-problem-detected) nor ["System Program Problem Detected"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174798/system-program-problem-detected).
I do ***not*** want to disable apport. I want to find a way to know what is the Problem the system detected and find a way of fix it.

This notification appears everytime I log in:
[image: Saucy Salamander]

I am using *Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander 32Bit*.

### Edits:

**1.** Apport won't come up when clicking ***Report Problem***.
**2.** Cairo-Dock won't start sporadically.
**3.** Login takes longer than expected.
**4.** Chrome crashes from time to time.
**5.** Laptop will overheat when CPU usage.

Comment: When you click "Report problem...", apport will come up, and will be able to give you more in-depth information. Would you mind copying and pasting the output from apport, please? Keep in mind, it may take a few seconds for apport to get all of the information, so be patient. :)

Comment: okay, that's fine, we can try to work this out without apport. Have you been experiencing any issues besides these errors appearing (eg. Unity crashes, programs crash, slow logout/login)?

Comment: I have the same thing here. I'm on Asus N76W laptop, what is your machine?

Comment: @Hans I have found that there are some issues with i5 processor on this machine, when it is running at 100% (no, not only heat sinking). BOINC, for example, produces invalid results. This is why i have asked.

Comment: @Hans Chrome tends to crash quite a bit (I don't know if they fixed that in this most recent update), but since you are getting the error dialog at login, the culprit may be Cario-Dock. It might be crashing quite a bit, but catching itself most of the time and restarting. Other times it might not be so lucky. Consider uninstalling Cario-Dock with `sudo apt-get remove cario-dock`. If this doesn't solve the problem, you can reinstall it without having to redownload by simply issuing `sudo apt-get install cario-dock` again.

Comment: Generally the system program problem detected pops up just after a application exits due to a bug.This is not always the case though.I will try to recreate some bug and then write an answer with necessary screenshots.For now,if you click **report problem**,it should show another window.Now click on the small arrows to expand report.You may see the application which caused the bug there somewhere.If you don't get me,don't mind,I'll try to write a good answer if I could recreate some bug.

Comment: @Hans that's definitely not right. Try removing all programs with the prefix of "cario" by using `sudo apt-get remove cario*`

Comment: @Hans if `sudo apt-get remove cario*` comes up with nothing, then yes, try `sudo apt-get remove Cario*`. I'm not completely familiar with the exact package names, and Linux has always been very case-sensitive when it comes to pretty much anything.

Comment: @Hans oh, right, my bad. I tend to mispronounce/misread/miseverything that first word. :)

Comment: @Hans right, that's why I had suggested removing any programs under `cairo*`. As for the package files, I believe that unless you issue `purge` in lieu of `remove`, the .DEB files remain on your hard drive for convenience purposes.

Comment: Have you tried to see if any crash reports are exist in `/var/crash/` directory ?

Comment: @Hans - please  can you summarise the above rather lengthy comments by editing your question.  Then you can delete your comments to cleanup.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by improving keyboard shortcuts in the Cairo-Dock app:

- Corrected **Lock Screen Shortcut** as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> somehow is not allowed.
- Corrected **Use Keyboard to navigate Cairo Dock** as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is somehow not allowed.