# Details regarding System program Problem Detected?

Tags: system, detect

My Questions could be a similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163025/system-program-problem-detected).
But i need...

[image: System Problem Detected]

Where does the problem will be reported?

What would happen if we cancel it?

What could be the possible Reasons of such occurrence?

Is there any Log/History files to view the sent Report?

How to know that the problem was solved or being solved?

Ways to report it manually, if we found? Do Help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where does the problem will be reported?

[Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net) in general and specifically: to the package the crash occurred on. By the way: if this specific crash is already known you will get a notice regarding that.

> What would happen if we cancel it?

No report will be filed.

> What could be the possible Reasons of such occurrence?

Bug in a program. Faulty hardware. Unsupported features in hardware.

> Is there any Log/History files to view the sent Report?

The program [apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) (Ubuntu specific) stores crashes in `/var/crash`. (See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport and [this on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139071/what-are-files-in-var-crash)).

> How to know that the problem was solved or being solved?

Track down the bugreport number and visit [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net).

> Ways to report it manually, if we found?

Sure you can manually report a bug on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net) BUT *you will need to get **all** the information added to a bug report* otherwise it will be marked as "incomplete".

Comment: Thanks a lot@Rinzwind. But, How it (launchpad) will detect the problem and can we able to send it via terminal.

Comment: That would be apprt-cli. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/apport-cli.1.html But that probably means you need to gather all of the data yourself. And it is a lot.

Comment: Thanks again @Rinzwind but is it good to delete the **Crash Folder** ? Gimme the command to send it via terminal with an example! please !!!

Comment: see http://www.linux-commands-examples.com/apport-cli And you can delete the crash folder anytime you like.

Comment: Really I've got a valid answers according to each Question. Thanks a lot @Rinzwind