# What is causing System program problem detected?

Tags: 18.04

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413871/what-is-system-program-problem-detected-notification-about-and-how-to-fix-it) didn't solve my problem since it is user specific.

And these two are just about disabling apport/ignoring error 
[System Program Problem Detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163025/system-program-problem-detected)
["System Program Problem Detected"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174798/system-program-problem-detected)

So upon booting every time it gives me pop up from the image, how do I find out what is causing it?
When I click "report problem" it doesn't show any details it just closes this pop-up. I don't recall installing/uninstalling any software before it started showing me this. I use an up-to-date 18.04 in a dual boot with Windows 7.

[image: System program problem detected]

I have crash report in /var/crash/ named _usr_bin_Xwayland.122.crash and I have no idea what am I looking at since it has bunch of base64 code and info I don't understand

Comment: Look in /var/log/crash for a .crash file corresponding to the boot date/time. Open the .crash file in any text editor. That will tell you what the problem is in great detail.

Comment: You could go on and press "Report problem", at some point before sending the collected data, you will have a chance to read details.

Comment: @BlackCloud .. you mean that "Report problem" goes directly to send a report ?

Comment: When I press "Send report" nothing happens it just closes window from image and that's it.

Comment: @user535733 /var/log/crash doesn't exist I guess you meant /var/chrash

Comment: Indeed /var/crash. Sorry for the misleading typo.

Comment: It sounds like at SOME POINT Wayland crashed.  When crashes like this happen, SOMETIMES there is nothing useful in the crash report as it's got a coredump and stacktrace and such for uploading to errors.ubuntu.com or similar for crash reporting.  If you don't know how to dissect crash reports you should probably just either ignore them or remove the crash report so the notice you see every time goes away.  (Usually you need technical knowledge to read/dissect the crash reports and stack traces, which if you don't have it you won't get any use from the crash file)

Comment: @ThomasWard So if I delete crash file it shouldn't throw error at me? Yup, I don't have knowledge to read it, it is quite complicated where on Android I could understand something. Anyway what is purpose of Wayland, because if this have any influence in login prompt for me it is choosen Ubuntu communitytheme on xorg and I have option to choose ubuntu wayland so I guess it has something to do with KDE?

Comment: @BlackCloud Yes you can remove the crash file.  If it regenerates every boot then something is wrong with Wayland.  Wayland details can be found here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Wayland  (though the development of it is stopped and we're back on GNOME based environments since 18.04)  It was a 'replacement' for underlying X.Org graphics 'server' systems that serve the GUI.  We're still using X.Org now and Mir/Wayland are not a thing as much.

Comment: @BlackCloud check your login screen. Locate the cogwheel icon, click it, and see what your default environment is set to... it may be something like `Ubuntu on Wayland`. Change that to `Ubuntu`, and your Wayland crashes should be gone. If not, there's a file that you need to edit to completely eliminate Wayland starting.

Comment: @heynnema For me it is set to Ubuntu communitytheme on Xorg, I'll try deleting crash report and and swithing to "Ubuntu communitytheme" to see if it makes difference.